# How can I access widgets inside methods without using findChild on PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm a newbie on PyQt and I'm making a small chat like application. I initialized the GUI and created several methods to manage user input. Problem is, I can't make use of the self.Method() instruction as shown in tutorials on the net. For some reason Python tells me that **object has no attribute 'WIDGET'**  where WIDGET in this case is the QListWidget.

I managed to overcome that using findChild but I'm not sure that's the right way to do it. What's the right way to access widgets from within a method on PyQt?

Here's my code:

```
import stuff *
class ASIMOV(QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 12))

        botLog = QListWidget(self)
        botLog.resize(150, 150)

        botInput = QLineEdit(self)
        botInput.returnPressed.connect(self.handleChatInput)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(botLog)
        vbox.addWidget(botInput)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.resize(600, 400)
        self.show()

    def startChat(self, botLog):
        u = ASIMOV_user.User()
        #Greet user
        botLog.addItem('#: Hey there' + u.getName())
        botChat = ASIMOV_chat.Chat()

    def handleChatInput(self):
        u = ASIMOV_user.User()
        print(self.botLog.text())
        botInput = self.findChild(QLineEdit, "")
        botLog = self.findChild(QListWidget, "")
        #lineEdits = self.findChildren(QLineEdit)
        botLog.addItem('#' + u.getName() + ': ' + botInput.text())
        #print(botInput.text())

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ASIMOV()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Also, must I initialize a class everytime I want to access their method such as the getters from the ASIMOV_user class?

Comment: Store a reference to the widgets when you create them by making them instance attributes (eg `self.botInput = QLineEdit(self)`). Then you can access them in the same way (`self.botInput`) from any method of your class. I'd suggest running through some basic tutorials on object oriented programming with Python to become familiar with the concepts you'll need to successfully write GUI programs.

Comment: Oh I see that makes sense, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer given by three_pineapples. In this case the original code has the widgets declared without the self operator which makes them local elements.

As he described, it only requires to add self.WIDGET to make them available to the rest of the methods in the application.

Original answer here:

> Store a reference to the widgets when you create them by making them
>   instance attributes (eg self.botInput = QLineEdit(self)). Then you can
>   access them in the same way (self.botInput) from any method of your
>   class. I'd suggest running through some basic tutorials on object
>   oriented programming with Python to become familiar with the concepts
>   you'll need to successfully write GUI programs